# whats the difference when building app with development and adhoc both allow to build in device

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I saw many question similar to this one. But my question is that .ipa created for testing using development provisioning or using adhoc distribution provisioning, What is the difference in both ipa?

in both i am able to archive and build in my device.

Comment: if you using push notification, for dev you should use dev certificate, for adhoc - production cert

Comment: but i can use push notification in both the profile, then whats the reason.

Comment: in adhoc you can test pushes which will be in appstore

Comment: ad-hoc will replicate app store release

Comment: thnx. appreciated. well dats the only difference i guess ?